# f(x)=sin(1/x), compute f'(-1/x)

Tags: chain-rule

$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Compute $f'(-\frac{1}{x})$.

While this problem isn't particularly hard, I noticed desmos gave a different answer from me.

What I did was (to be safe), $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Therefore, $f'(-\frac{1}{x})=-\frac{1}{x^4}\cos\left(-x\right)=-\frac{1}{x^4}\cos\left(x\right)$.

Did I make a mistake in here? And if so where?

Checking back to the differentials, df/dv = df/dx * dx/dv. dx/dv = x^2, and df/dx = -1/x^2 cos(1/x). did i make a mistake somewhere in there, is that why desmos shows -cosx as the answer?

what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivative is wrong. $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is correct.

Hence $f'(-\frac{1}{x})=-\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{x})^2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{x}}\right)=-x^2 \cos(-x)=-x^2 \cos(x)$

Comment: that's what DESMOS got!!

Answer (score 2):

Write $f'(y) = \frac{-1}{y^{2}}\cos (\frac{1}{y})$. Now if $y := -1/x$ then
$$
f'(y) = f'(-1/x) = -x^{2}\cos (-x) = -x^{2}\cos (x).
$$

Comment: what about chain rule??

Comment: Let $g(x):=f(-1/x)$. Then $g'(x) \ne f'(-1/x)$ !

Comment: @Saketh, I dealt with not the chain rule; instead, I was implying that the OP was confused by the symbols used.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I understand.

The chain rule says d/dx f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)

however, f'(g(x)) never calls for the chain rule.

also, i forgot to substitute -1/x for 1/x^2 when plugging in

Comment: That is it! :)  )